# ASP.NET MVC2 Browser caching with HTTP304 Status Code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, browser-cache, http-status-code-304

In the company I work for, we have a web application developed with ASP.NET MVC2 and hosted on IIS7.

In a specific action, we return a JsonResult object holding an array. This array is updated daily; so any request coming in the same day will end up with the same response.

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(int id)
{
    // Some calculations
    return Json(resultArray, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Since the operation is costly, we wanted to improve performance with browser caching and so.

I added a cache header, so we are telling user browser to cache the result till the next update of the database.

Besides that, I want to add a "Last-Modified" header, so browser will ask for if the source is modified after the specified date.

What is the way to accomplish that? I want to check if DB is modified after the date browser asked (Last-Modified header) and if not modified, I want to return 304 just IIS automatically does for static files (images, css and js files etc)

Comment: [You know about the output cache attribute, right?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx)

Comment: Yes, but outputcache attribute needs compile-time defined duration, I need to check DB on runtime for last modified date.

Comment: That's right. But what's your actual question? It sounds like you have everything figured out. If you set Expires and Last-Modified and the Cache-Control stuff, shouldn't everything just work?

Comment: I am using Expires, MaxAge, Cacheability successfully. But I couldn't figure out how to use Last-Modified header and check if browser is asking with "If-Modified-Since" header. So right now, if browser sends request with "If-modified-since" header, I am sending HTTP200 in any way. Thanks for your help by the way :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a truthful `Last-Modified` header. If your data is updated daily, you should know when, right?

Then, in the beginning of the action method, add a check for the incoming `If-Modified-Since` by parsing that datetime string in the HTTP request and checking against the actual last-modified time of your data. If the data hasn't been modified, just [return 304 manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809987/asp-net-mvc-how-do-i-return-304-not-modified-status). If it has, do what the action method normally does.

You could also (or instead) return an [ETag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) with your content, the value of which must then change whenever the content changes.

Then wrap the whole thing up as an [ASP.NET MVC Action Filter](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/understanding-action-filters-cs) for reusability.

Then [post about it on your blog. :)](http://www.58bits.com/blog/2009/07/26/asp-net-mvc-304-not-modified-filter-for-syndication-content/)

To protect against misbehaving clients and clients who don't cache anything (perhaps your data is loaded by an application and not a desktop browser), you could store the result of the action method in the ASP.NET output cache anyway, to avoid the costly operation. You'd probably [have to `VaryByCustom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.getvarybycustomstring.aspx) to implement absolute expiration though.

Comment: Thanks for kind answer :) I first visited 58bits via link you gave, are you the author of the blog post? I just wonder.

Comment: Nope. It just seemed similar to what you need.