# Configure the MVC.NET OutputCache to return 304 Not Modified if an ActionResult hasn't changed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outputcache

**Introduce the Problem**

We have successfully configured the browser cache to return a saved response if the server indicates `304 Not Modified`. Here is the config:

```
<caching>
  <outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
      <add
        name="TransparentClient"
        location="Client"
        duration="0" />
    </outputCacheProfiles>
  </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

The web.config is perfect and sets `Cache-control:private, max-age=0` so that:

1. The browser will cache responses,
2. will *always* validate the cache, and
3. will return the cached response if the server responds 304.

The problem is that our MVC.NET Actions always respond 200 and never 304.

**The Problem**

How do we configure output caching to return a 304 Not Modified when an ActionResult hasn't changed?

- Is there any built-in cache validation in MVC.NET?
- If it isn't, how do we roll-our-own cache validation mechanism?

The roll-our-own will probably require an Action Filter with ETag or Last-Modified.

**Screen Shots**

Here is a Fiddler screenshot showing the lack of a 304.

- ## 318 is a SHIFT+Refresh.
- ## 332 is a Refresh that we expected would result in a 304. Problem.

[image: Fiddler Web Debugger]

**Search and Research**

[ASP.NET MVC : how do I return 304 "Not Modified" status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809987/asp-net-mvc-how-do-i-return-304-not-modified-status) mentions returning a 304 from within the Action. That does not provide a way to make the OutputCache accurately respond with a 304.

[Working with the Output Cache and other Action Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990337/working-with-the-output-cache-and-other-action-filters) shows how to override the OnResultExecuted, which will allow adding/removing headers.

Comment: You probably meant #332...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following is working for us.

## Web.Config

Set `Cache-Control:private,max-age-0` to enable caching and force re-validation.

```
<system.web>
  <caching>
    <outputCacheSettings>
      <outputCacheProfiles>
        <add name="TransparentClient" duration="0" location="Client" />
      </outputCacheProfiles>
    </outputCacheSettings>
  </caching>
</system.web>
```

## Action

Respond with 304 if the response is not modified.

```
[MyOutputCache(CacheProfile="TransparentClient")]
public ActionResult ValidateMe()
{
    // check whether the response is modified
    // replace this with some ETag or Last-Modified comparison
    bool isModified = DateTime.Now.Second < 30;

    if (isModified)
    {
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(304, "Not Modified");
    }
}
```

## Filter

Remove the `Cache-Control:private,max-age-0` otherwise the cache will store the status message.

```
public class MyOutputCache : OutputCacheAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 304)
        {
            // do not cache the 304 response                
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.CacheControl = "";                
        }
    }
}
```

## Fidder

Fiddler shows that the cache is acting appropriately.

[image: Successful Fiddler]