# How to return a 304 result from ASP.NET Core web api?

Tags: asp.net-core

I've been returning HTTP status codes from within my ASP.NET Core web api as follows:

```
// Return code 200:
return Controller.Ok(someOptionalMessageHere);
```

I now have the need to return a status code 304 (i.e. not modified), but I don't see anything from intellisense in the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller" class that does that, nor do those namespaces appear in the online API browser (?). What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as i know there is no explicit method for 304.

But you could use

```
return  Controller.StatusCode(304,ObjectYouWantToReturn);
```

Edit: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.statuscode?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is a link to the documentation

Comment: Docs link ironically returns a 404, this is the right one I think: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.statuscode

Answer (score 4):

As the eTag specification says you don't return content for a 304 (not modified) I suggest you do this instead:

```
return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.NotModified);
```

Comment: Would advise using the StatusCodes from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http for ASP Core. i.e.  
   return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status304NotModified);

Answer (score 0):

Followings work for .NET Core minimal API.

```
return Results.StatusCode(304);
```

or

```
return Results.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status304NotModified);
```